# How to autoinsert in editable data Table inPHP

Tags: php, sql, datatable

I want to insert some values to a grade from a editable table (course) after i add presence, coursework, midExam, final exam, total, grade

```
|Id_Student|Id_Course|Semester|Presence|Coursework|MidExam|FinalExam|Total|Grade|
|          |         |        |        |          |       |         |     |     |
```

this my code
I just want to add auto insert in Grade row for this rule
Total > 80 Grade is A, Total = 70 - 79 Gradeis B, Total = 60-69 Grade is C, Total = 50-59 Grade is D, Total < 50 Grade is E

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST",
        },
        createdRow:function(row, data, rowIndex)
        {
            $.each($('td', row), function(colIndex){
                if(colIndex == 1)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Id_Student');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Id_Student');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 2)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Name');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Name');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 3)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Id_Course');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Id_Course');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 4)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Semester');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Semester');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 5)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Presence');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Presence');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 6)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Coursework');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Coursework');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 7)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'MidExam');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'MidExam');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 8)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'FinalExam');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'FinalExam');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 9)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Total');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Total');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                if(colIndex == 10)
                {
                    $(this).attr('data-name', 'Grade');
                    $(this).attr('class', 'Grade');
                    $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                    $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
                }
                
            });
        }
    });

    
    $('#sample_data').editable({
        container:'body',
        selector:'td.presence',
        url:'update.php',
        title:'presence',
        type:'POST',
        validate:function(value){
            if($.trim(value) == '')
            {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
        }
    });

    $('#sample_data').editable({
        container:'body',
        selector:'td.Coursework',
        url:'update.php',
        title:'Coursework',
        type:'POST',
        validate:function(value){
            if($.trim(value) == '')
            {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
        }
    });

    $('#sample_data').editable({
        container:'body',
        selector:'td.MidExam',
        url:'update.php',
        title:'MidExam',
        type:'POST',
        validate:function(value){
            if($.trim(value) == '')
            {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
        }
    });

    $('#sample_data').editable({
        container:'body',
        selector:'td.FinalExam',
        url:'update.php',
        title:'FinalExam',
        type:'POST',
        validate:function(value){
            if($.trim(value) == '')
            {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
        }
    });
    $('#sample_data').editable({
        container:'body',
        selector:'td.Total',
        url:'update.php',
        title:'Total',
        type:'POST',
        validate:function(value){
            if($.trim(value) == '')
            {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
        }
    });
    $('#sample_data').editable({
        container:'body',
        selector:'td.Grade',
        url:'update.php',
        title:'Grade',
        type:'POST',
        validate:function(value){
            if($.trim(value) == '')
            {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
        }
    });
    }); 
</script>
```